# discord.js check if a particualr user ID has a particular role ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have some code which I want to; get all the users with a particular role (their 'team'). Then for each of those users in the particular team I want to investigate some of the other roles they have.

I have the teams (roles) in an arrary, so I can loop through each team.

```
//pop a role to work with for this loop
const therole = teams.pop();

//find role for this loop
const Role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == therole );

//filtered by those with therole for the loop, fill members array with users ids with that role
const Members = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.roles.cache.find(role => role == Role)).map(member => member.user.id);
```

At this point I now have an arrary Members which contains the member ids of the users with role 'therole'. This part works.

What I then want to do for each of the member ids stored in the Members arrary is lookup that member and check if they have various other roles (for example, I have a timezone role).

So I start a loop

```
for (var i=Members.length; i--;){
```

but I am stuck on how to lookup the member by the ID in the Members arrary and check if they have another role. The closest I have got is;

```
var haseurope = message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === 'Europe');

//Debug log
console.log(i + ' The member is:' + Members[i]);        
console.log(i + ' Has Europe is:' + haseurope);
```

The Members arrary is 6 IDs long and sometimes I can get the haseurope to equal true 6 times, sometimes false 6 times depending on how I define haseurope variable. The above example logs (IDs anonomoised);

```
app[worker.1]: 5 The member is:684896007655557000
app[worker.1]: 5 Has Europe is:true
app[worker.1]: 4 The member is:489439004133708000
app[worker.1]: 4 Has Europe is:true
app[worker.1]: 3 The member is:110047003303981000
app[worker.1]: 3 Has Europe is:true
app[worker.1]: 2 The member is:589135008044626000
app[worker.1]: 2 Has Europe is:true
app[worker.1]: 1 The member is:218202002409912000
app[worker.1]: 1 Has Europe is:true
app[worker.1]: 0 The member is:341509003306030000
app[worker.1]: 0 Has Europe is:true
```

I think what is happenening is that when I am running `message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === 'Europe');` the member part is not changing for each itteration of the loop. I don't seem to be able to do something like this though;

```
message.Members[i].roles.cache.some(r => r.name === 'Europe');
```

How can I check; "For each ID in the Members arrary, does this user ID have the 'Europe' role?

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```js
let members = message.guild.members.cache.array();
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Europe');
for(let member of members) {
   let hasRole = member.roles.cache.has(role.id);
   console.log(`${member.id}: ${hasRole}`);
}
```

This is a simple example of how you can find out which user has the "Europe" role. `members` is the array of GuildMembers. `role` is the role. Then I used a basic foreach loop. In `hasRole` we check if the member has the role.

Example output:

```
283929434854129664: true 
292953664492929025: false
```

Comment: It looks like this code gets all server members and checks them all for the "Europe" role. Is there a way to restrict this to just looking up the user IDs I already have saved in my arrary called Members?

When I run your example, it seems to output the member ID of all 30+ members on our server.